# Check if Python package on git is newer than local

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a package which is distributed by asking people to run:

`pip install git+"https://gitlab.com/project/mypackage.git@master"`

I would like to have a Python script which when run flags that the local package is older than the remote one *(I want to avoid automatically updating it)*.

I was thinking to do the below, say `check_version.py`

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version, get_distribution
local_version = parse_version(get_distribution("mypackage").version)

def foo()
    # GET GIT REPO PACKAGE VERSION
    return repo_version

repo_version = foo()

if local_version < repo_version:
    print("Local Installation is out of date")
else:
    print("Local Installation is up to date.")
```

However I am not sure how to query the git repo to get the version number... Basically *`foo`* function should be implemented, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: git has command-line interface. Call via python git commands, and execute them in foo function. Did you check how to call git commands via command line?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple text file `VERSION` in your repository that only has the current version. Every file at Gitlab has a raw URL; your file will be available at `https://gitlab.com/project/mypackage/raw/master/VERSION`. Read the content of the URL in `foo` using `httplib/http.client` or `urllib` or `requests`, whatever.